# icon and text inline css issue

Tags: css

Where have a i gone wrong here

```
ul.bullet { list-style-image:url('../images/bullet-blue-icon.png');vertical-align:middle;line-height:16px; }
ul.bullet li { line-height:16px;font-size:14px;}
```

The image is 16px x 16px

Should dispplay absolutley inline with the li text so like this

[ image ] text here

But the image is off cock, [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the background image to the `LI` rather then the `UL`. Then set the background position for the image.

Something along the lines of:

```
ul{
list-style:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

ul li{
background:url(image/path.png) left center no-repeat;
padding-left:20px;
}
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work. You can, of course, still have `margin` and/or `padding` on your `UL` if you wish - this is just for the example.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted =D